# change of address to subdomain

Tags: google-search-console, 301-redirect

I have moved a domain "`http://flymusic`" to "`http://www.1.flymusic`".

The "Change of Address Tool" in webmasters tools won't allow me to tell Google about the new URL because it is a sub-domain.
and the error is "Restricted to root level domains only"

I see in Google webmaster guide that:

> "Make sure that your new site is not a subdomain. For example, you can
>   use www.example.com, but not `www.example.com/newsite` or
>   `http://newsite.example.com`."

This site has several thousand links and was doing well on SERPs and I would hate to lose the momentum that I have established.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you still own the first domain you can do a 301 redirect. Check https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633

Comment: thanks and what do i do in google webmaster?